# Import Error: Cannot import function after clearly declaring in the __init__.py

Tags: python, importerror

Say, I have three files **`__init__.py`**, **`time.py`** and **`readers.py`** in a directory *analogpy*.

**`time.py`** has a class and **`readers.py`** has function **`read_file()`**

**`__init__.py`** has following

```
from analogpy import time
from analogpy import readers
```

when I import **readers** from analogpy and call the function **read_file()**, it shows the following error

```
from analogpy import readers
ImportError: cannot import name 'read_file' from 'analogpy' (analogpy/__init__.py)
```

Functions are clearly defined because I see they work fine when compiling individual files. What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can update your `__init__.py` like this:

```py
from .readers import read_file
```

then you can from analogpy import readfile in other file and call the function

2. or you can use

```py
from analogpy import readers

readers.read_file()
```

to call the function